# Why not to use "Link Answers"

Tags: discussion

I have one pet peeve on this site - the notorious *Link Answer.* I review often, and this is an issue that I have seen come up frequently. I know I am being a hypocrite, but here is a list of reasons to *not* use link-answers.

1. **Link Rot**

   Ever wonder what happens if they site you linked to goes down? That's right, we have a useless link. Because of this, links are a *very* bad way to explain answers.
2. **Not Your Own Work**

   Obviously, links are *not your own work.* Even if the information is free, it is important to treat the original author and the community with respect. For this reason, it is better to *explain the link,* and then use a link for *credit* **not** *explanation.*
3. **Lowers the Value of Original Work on Stack Exchange**

   Having  a link answer lowers the value of *all answers around it.* A new user may ask him or herself *Why take the time and effort to ask a question if all I get is a link from a Google Search?* This leaves a bad taste in their mouth, and is thus detrimental to the community as a whole.

**Please do not use link answers as they are not useful, subject to change, disrespectful, and annoying.**

Comment: Also, how do I make a question community wiki?

Comment: This isn't a question :)

Answer (score 4):

I think you'll find this topic discussed a lot elsewhere :)

[Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

[Should I flag answers which contain only a link as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer)

[How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Obviously I'm being slightly ironic. But seriously, an answer with links doesn't constitute a good answer for many reasons. Just vote down and suggest the poster summarises the external source.

Comment: Or even better: click the link and edit the answer based on what you learn.