# Piversify - The community driven blog dedicated to the Raspberry Pi

Tags: discussion

[**Piversify**](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/) is a blog dedicated to the Raspberry Pi, written by members of the raspberrypi.stackexchange.com community.

---

Learn more about the *why, what, who, and how-to* here: [We Started a Blog!](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/755/we-started-a-blog) Now that we have been in business for more than half a year I would like to ask you all for your opinion on the progress so far. We're also open for any ideas and recommendations regarding improvements including actions to increase its visibility. Last but not least I would very much like to solicit your contribution of interesting content to the blog!

---

<sup><sub>One idea is to have this post "featured" on meta so that it will show up on the main page to lure people here and prominently link to the blog.</sub></sup>

Answer (score 7):

## Contributions

- [Raspberry Pi Display Options](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/150747499464)
- [SSH Security and Usability – Part 6](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/150078167619)
- [SSH Security and Usability – Part 5](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/149800066154)
- [SSH Security and Usability – Part 4](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/149429965524)
- [SSH Security and Usability – Part 3](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/148725075714)
- [SSH Security and Usability – Part 2](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/148401541394)
- [SSH Security and Usability – Part 1](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/148032481829)
- [Securing your Raspberry Pi with Let's Encrypt](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/149134418729)
- [Ad Hoc Networking with Raspberry Pis](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/147699665389)
- [Quick Links 2](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/147097749654)
- [Tracking Your System’s Configuration Changes with Etckeeper](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/146996830774)
- [Quick Links](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/146759674604)
- [An Introduction to Crontab](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/146656710649)
- [Improving the Usability of the Nano Editor](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/146308635329)
- [Making Bash History More Useful](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/145241995159)
- [Setting up a LAMP stack on a Raspberry Pi - Part 1](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/144922590364)
- [Exploring the 3.3V Power Rail](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/144555785379)
- [Storing Data on a Raspberry Pi](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/144202547329)
- [Camera Module Part 1: Getting started](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/143828902324)
- [Tmux 102: Getting to know Tmux](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/143463394889)
- [Improving Your Command Line Skills Part 4](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/143121276514)
- [Improving Your Command Line Skills Part 3](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/142634263599)
- [Improving Your Command Line Skills Part 2](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/142215518744)
- [Improving Your Command Line Skills Part 1](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/141758901139)
- [Tmux 101: Installing from Source](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/141348857424)
- [Installing Applications on a Raspberry Pi Running Raspbian](https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/post/140986024839)

Keep notified: https://raspberrypise.tumblr.com/rss

Answer (score 1):

## Spread the word

- Reference to blog posts in your answers or comments on the main page <sub><sup>(note that we do not ask to provide [link-only answers!](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/842/cleaning-up-link-only-answers))</sup></sub>